# Gerrit draft deleted accidentally, commit saved locally.

Tags: git, gerrit

I have accidentally deleted the draft from gerrit but still have the commit locally. When I try to push the commit, it tries to push with the same commit ID and hence fails since it can't find it on gerrit anymore. I am thinking of creating a new branch off the origin and putting all my changes to that new branch and push a fresh commit. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just need to amend your commit (git commit --amend) and change the Change-Id (a number like Ic84b525d6b6920c90295e297afd7da435c441a7a). Gerrit is trying to use the old change due to this number.

You can remove the Change-Id line and generate a new one or you can just change some aleatory numbers (like change the above number to Ic147ab5d6b6920c90295e297afd7da435c441a7a), this is enough.

To learn more about the Change-Ids take a look at Gerrit documentation [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-changeid.html).

Comment: I did it my way anyway but for anyone else who comes across it in future, any ideas in how to generate the ID?

Comment: I updated the answer with more info about the Change-Ids.

Comment: I tried this on a later change and your solution works just fine. Just amend the ID